# Why is my CPU running slower than it should be?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cpu-speed

I have an AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-core processor that should run at 3.30 GHz, however upon trying to overclock the processor (which I never got around to doing) I have found that it is running at 1.4 GHz with a multiplier of 7. Also the voltage keeps changing.

I haven't had the computer for very long, perhaps a year or two, but I've only just come across this.

I've tried running the PC in high performance mode and also changing the maximum processor state to 100% with no success.

**System details:**

- AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-core processor (3.30 Ghz)
- Gigabyte M68MT-S2 Motherboard
- ZOTAC GeForce GTX 560 2GB

Here is a screenshot of my ET6 states:
[image]

Comment: Try to overload cpu with some program in the background and then while it's working check your cpu clock.

Answer (score 1):

AMD has 'CnQ' tech to slow the clock to reduce heat production.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool%27n%27Quiet

If there are some programs (such as benchmark) require heavy CPU workloads, the CPU freq will back to 3G.

Comment: "I've tried running the PC in high performance mode and also changing the maximum processor state to 100% with no success" Indicates he tried that I think

Comment: @JourneymanGeek "maximum processor state" should also modify "minimal processor state" field. This may help. Alternate solution is run benchmark program and fill CPU usage to 100%